# sqlalchemy-access: Table already exists

Tags: python, pandas, ms-access, pyodbc, sqlalchemy-access

---

Update: I tried running the script from another computer with an earlier version of sqlalchemy-access (1.1.2 instead of 1.1.3) the script worked. When I installed 1.1.2 on the computer that gave the error, I got

```
NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:access.pyodbc
```

Both computers are updating the same access table (which is saved on a network drive).

---

I am updating an existing MS Access table using a dataframe (all_results_df):

```
cnn_str = r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\data\MyData.accdb;'
cnn_url = f"access+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={urllib.parse.quote_plus(cnn_str)}"
acc_engine = create_engine(cnn_url)
all_results_df.to_sql('results', acc_engine, if_exists='append')
```

and I get the following error:

> ProgrammingError: ('42S01', "[42S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Table 'results' already exists. (-1303) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Why doesn't it just append the new data to the existing table?

Comment: from [this issue at github](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/269) issue it appears the problems is that MSAccess needs a confirmation (or to have the alerts disabled - which probably can't be done in pyodbc). You might be able to disable alerts on the database as an option. Otherwise you might pursue the same workaround mentioned there.

Comment: @topsail, those messages are part of the MSAccess.exe software not the Access database engine. Recall "Access" is a [multifaceted thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33216/ms-access-or-mdb-or-access-database-engine-or-ms-jet-ace) that can be accessed on frontend with the Office app or backend via ODBC/OLEDB. Action DML or DDL queries via backend connection as OP attempts do not require user confirmation.

Comment: Please post the `dtypes` of data frame and table design of `results` table. We need to see your table column fields for any special data types.

Comment: Is the table really named `results`? If the table name actually contains accented characters then you may have run into [this issue](https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlalchemy-access/issues/17), which was fixed in sqlalchemy-access version 1.1.3.

Comment: I updated the question with additional information.

Comment: @Parfait the ```dtypes``` are all either object or float64.

@Gord Thompson The table is actually named ```bat_results```, so no accented characters.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, updating ms-access solved the problem.